# capturePage in electron JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

This is my Code. I want to take a screenshot of the browserwindow. But its not taking the screenshot as epected. The window is offscreen. I want to take the screenshot asap the page loads and convert it to PNG. Can someone please help

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

// Offscreen BrowserWindow
let offscreenWindow

// Exported readItem function
module.exports = (url, callback) => {

  // Create offscreen window
  offscreenWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      offscreen: true
    }
  })

  // Load item url
  offscreenWindow.loadURL(url)
  console.log("readitem")

  // Wait for content to finish loading
  offscreenWindow.webContents.on('did-stop-loading', () => {

    // Get page title
    let title = offscreenWindow.getTitle()
    console.log(title)

    // Get screenshot (thumbnail)
    offscreenWindow.capturePage( image => {

        fs.writeFile('test.png', image.toPNG(), (err) => {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('It\'s saved!')})})


      // Get image as dataURL
      //let screenshot = image.toDataURL()


      // Execute callback with new item object
      callback({ title, url })

      // Clean up
      offscreenWindow.close()
      offscreenWindow = null

  })}
```

Comment: Windows : 10
electro version:8.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created this file using your. Its working and tested. You need to use [contents.capturePage([rect])](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentscapturepagerect)

`offscreenWindow.webContents.capturePage().then(image=>{ //something done})`  then write the image to the dis synchronously by using `fs.writeSync()`

**screenshot.js**

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
// Offscreen BrowserWindow
let offscreenWindow
let nativeImage
// Exported readItem function
module.exports = (url, callback) => {

    // Create offscreen window
    offscreenWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            offscreen: true
        }
    })

    // Load item url
    offscreenWindow.loadURL(url)
    console.log("readitem")

    // Wait for content to finish loading
    offscreenWindow.webContents.on('did-stop-loading', async() => {

        // Get page title
        let title = offscreenWindow.getTitle()
        console.log(title)

        // Get screenshot (thumbnail)
        nativeImage = await offscreenWindow.webContents.capturePage().then(image => {
            fs.writeFileSync('test.png', image.toPNG(), (err) => {
                if (err) throw err
            })
            console.log('It\'s saved!')
            return image.toDataURL()

        })
        let obj = { title:title, 
            url: url,
            image: nativeImage }
        callback(obj) 
        // Clean up
        offscreenWindow.close()
        offscreenWindow = null

    })
}
```

**main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require("path")
const fs = require("fs")
const screenshot = require("./screen")
let  window 

function createWindow () {
    window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  window.loadFile("./index.html")
  window.webContents.openDevTools()
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

ipcMain.on("start::screenshot", (event,arg) => {
  console.log("Starting")
  screenshot(arg, (reply) => {console.log("It's completed", reply)})
})
```

**renderer.js**

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

function start() {
    console.log("start")
    let args = "https://google.com"
    ipcRenderer.send('start::screenshot',args)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. What if I want to pass the screenshot also in call back after converting it like: image.toDataURL()

Comment: This is my code: 
let offscreenWindow

module.exports = (url, callback) => {

  
  offscreenWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      offscreen: true
    }
  })
  offscreenWindow.loadURL(url)
  offscreenWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', e => {
    
    let title = offscreenWindow.getTitle()

    offscreenWindow.webContents.capturePage( image => {
      let screenshot = image.toDataURL()
      callback({ title, screenshot, url })

    
      offscreenWindow.close()
      
    })
  })
}

Comment: Any updates? If you find this useful please upvote and accept so others can find this easily :)

Comment: hi.. I passed the screenshot as it is to the callback.it worked. thank you so much